# Cannot import my own module in scrapy crawler

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm writing a crawler using Scrapy. I've built a crawler and it works very well.

Now I want to create my own modules, but I always receive this error:

> File "D:\Projects\bitbucket\terranoha\crawl1\crawl1\spiders\samplecrawler.py", line 4, in 
>       import moduletest
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moduletest'

The code is:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import moduletest

class SamplecrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    # [...]
```

I am running:  `scrapy crawl --nolog  samplecrawler`. I'm on Windows 10.

My project structure is:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do several things:

**First**

```
from crawl1.spiders.moduletest import mythings
```

As suggested by @elRuLL

**Second**

```
from .moduletest import mythings
```

This generally a bad and brittle solution but possible.

**Third**

You can package it as package and do.

***init**.py:*

```
from spiders.moduletest import *
__all__ = [<Put your classes, methods, etc here>]
```

*samplecrawler.py*

```
import moduletest
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to include the full module path:

```
from crawl1.spiders.moduletest import mythings
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to include the name of the folder as the module name

```
import crawl1.spiders.moduletest
```

Answer (score 1):

Found, after some hours:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import crawl1.spiders.moduletest

class SamplecrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
```

**import crawl1.spiders.moduletest**