# ImportError No Module in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, filepath

I have a module (code from another repo) inside my own directory but I can't manage to use the scripts in that repo. Directory looks like this:

```
- project/
    - graph_analysis/
        - __init__.py
        - script1.py
        - script2.py
    -model.py
    -utils.py
    -main.py
```

I am using pycharm and I explicitely marked the graph_analysis module as source. My `__init__.py` is empty and I try to call the functions inside the module using the following format:

```
from graph_analysis.script1 import Call1
from graph_analysis.script2 import Call2
```

And I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named script1
```

Comment: Won't my answer to similar post help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871052/cannot-import-my-own-module-in-scrapy-crawler/53871206#answer-53871206

Comment: None of those options work :(

Comment: Could you try the following changes. In `script1.py`: `__all__ = ['call1']` and `call1 = Call1`. In `__init__.py`: `from graph_analysis.script1 import *` and finally in `project` add file `__init__.py` and in `main.py` add `from graph_analysis.script1 import call1`.

Comment: Could you also specify how your files interconnected and what do import where?